# Spring Data JPA. В сущности есть 2 поля одного типа. Как их правильно замаппить?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Есть 2 класса. Первый:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flight")
public class Flight {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "flightId", unique = true)
    private int id;

    private String number;

    private LocalDateTime date;

    @ManyToOne
    private Plane plane;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "departure_airport_id")
    private Airport departureAirport;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "arrival_airport_id")
    private Airport arrivalAirport;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "flight")
    private List<Ticket> tickets;

    @ManyToOne
    private Airline airline;
}
```

И второй:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Airport")
public class Airport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "airportId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "departureAirport")
    private List<Flight> departureFlights;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "arrivalAirport")
    private List<Flight> arrivalFlights;

}
```

Таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPORT(
  AIRPORT_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR (250)
);

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT(
  FLIGHT_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  NUMBER VARCHAR (50),
  PLANE_ID INTEGER REFERENCES PLANE(PLANE_ID),
  DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_ID INTEGER REFERENCES AIRPORT(AIRPORT_ID),
  ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_ID INTEGER REFERENCES AIRPORT(AIRPORT_ID),
  AIRLINE_ID INTEGER REFERENCES AIRLINE(AIRLINE_ID),
  DATE TIMESTAMP
);
```

При попытке запустить Spring Boot вылезает ошибка:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.foxminded.airline.Application.main(Application.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ограничение "fkor550l1m73innd911e6nm8lj0" в таблице "flight" не существует
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Может кто сталкивался

Comment: А почему вы аннотируете геттеры а не поля?

Comment: Ошибка скорее всего не в маппинге. При запуске spring пытается создать или обновить базу данных, и ему что-то мешает. Каким образом создаётся бд, миграциями или автоматически генерируется? Возможно поможет пересоздание бд с нуля

Comment: Да, возможно, spring пытается создать БД, так как при выключении spring boot все таблицы удаляются.